# C - Casting char array to an integer pointer?

Tags: c, casting

I have the following source code and there is one line, which i cannot understand the casting is been made. Can anyone explain please?
I know the casting to an integer pointer (int *) but this is different.
I cannot understand what the final line does. Is it returning an integer pointer? or i am wrong?

```
const unsigned char sc[] =  {  0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01   };
return ((int (*)(void))sc)();
```

Comment: Why don't you see the function definition and check what is it's return type?

Comment: the function prototype is the int main(), but i was looking forward to understand the meaning of the line and not only what returns

Comment: Is it working at all? Looks really weird. It calls an array as a function, while the array contents look nothing like executable code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(int (*)(void))sc` takes address of an array `sc` and converts it to a pointer to function which returns `int`.

`()` at the end then calls this function, and return value of this function (type `int`) is again returned.

Weird part is that it seems as if the intention was to call function at address `0x01010101`, but it uses the address of array `sc` instead, which may be an error.

Comment: Not it seems very logic to me now. That's the source code. http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/21252/. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, so the original array is different.